# How to include the session information in jQuery in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, erb

I am working on a jQuery chat room in ruby on rails and I am trying to include the current user's name. However, whenever I write

```
var user=<%= current_user.name %>
```

the chat room stops working. What is wrong with the above statement? The current_user method returns the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have been

```
var user = '<%= escape_javascript current_user.name %>';
```

Comment: Hopefully you don't have any O'Malleys on your site.

Comment: @mu is too short: Got your point. Somehow, the alias doesn't work for me. Only the actual helper does. Thanks for pointing out..

Comment: Version issue perhaps? I checked with 3.1 and that's all I've been using lately

Answer (score 1):

You want to quote and [properly escape](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) the name:

```
var user = '<%=j current_user.name %>';
```